# add resource in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to use some pictures as my resources in a windows phone 7 application. I used to add them in visual studio directly as resource, but which is not easy for update. What I want is I can put them in a folder in the application folder and then the application can use them.

Is it possible for me to do that? 
Thank you.

Comment: What's not easy to update about it? Bear in mind that at runtime, you cannot write to the application directory, only to your applications isolated storage.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can add items in a folder in your application and set their build action to content

Comment: But I don't want to do that in my visual studio in this app, I've got another app for maintain these data and resource, I just wanna add resource by that maintain application and then those resource can be used by the main app.

Comment: Could you give me some more advice?

Comment: The applications in WP are sandboxed ie they don't share data. To be more clear suppose an app stores data in the phone memory another app can not access that data, this has been done for security reasons. The resource file which you use in an app are kept inside the xap hence cannot be used by another app.

Comment: Then, is there any workaround, for example, add my resource files directly into the isolated storage, so they can be done by my maintain app but used by my main app?

Comment: @AaronZhang nope one isolated storage for one app exclusive and sandboxed but you can export your database to some place(A) and later on fetch it but you cannot change the structure of your database file kept at (A) but maybe you can add data to the existing database at (A) and retrieve it later